# Не получается получить данные через API

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

```
import requests

URL_AUTH = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/authenticate'
URL_TRANSLATE = 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard'
KEY = 'MY API KEY'

headers_auth = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + KEY}
auth = requests.post(URL_AUTH, headers=headers_auth)
print(auth.text)
language_1 = 'English'
language_2 = 'russian'

if auth.status_code == 200:
    token = auth.text
    print(token)
    word = input('enter {0}'.format(language_1))
    while True:
        if word:
            headers_translate = {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
            params = {
                'text': word,
                'srcLang': 1033,
                'dstLang': 1049
            }
            r = requests.get(URL_TRANSLATE, headers=headers_translate, params=params)
            res = r.json()
            try:
                print(res['Translation']['Translation'])
            except:
                print('Не удалось найти слово для перевода')
else:
    print('error')
```

Проверял через **postman**: все проходит. `print(r.status_code)` выдает 401, но нигде не могу найти ошибку, токен тоже находит без проблем.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Django/mysite/art/dcfvedv.py", line 28, in <module>
    res = r.json()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по документации, в частности к методу [GET api/v1/Minicard](https://developers.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/Help/Api/GET-api-v1-Minicard_text_srcLang_dstLang), формат запроса должен быть `text/json, application/json`.

Добавьте в начало скрипта:

```
import json
```

в `headers_translate`:

```
{
    'Content-type': 'application/json', 
    'Accept': 'text/json'
}
```

а параметры передавайте в `json`:

```
r = requests.get(
        URL_TRANSLATE, 
        headers=headers_translate, 
        params=json.dumps(params)
)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
NameError: name 'json' is not defined

[Program finished]

Comment: Уже другая ошибка

Comment: добавьте import json в начало скрипта (добавил в ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `params` используйте атрибут `json`, чтобы запрос был отправлен с `JSON`:

```
r = requests.get(URL_TRANSLATE, headers=headers_translate, json=params)
#                                                         ^^^^^^^
```